# Java Reflection - How to exclude interface when loading the class dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection

I use spring framework to find the class and its methods and arguments dynamically.

these are the methods I use :

```
public List<Class> findMyTypes(String basePackage) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory = new CachingMetadataReaderFactory(resourcePatternResolver);

        List<Class> candidates = new ArrayList<Class>();
        String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX +
                                   resolveBasePackage(basePackage) + "/" + "**/*.class";
        Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(packageSearchPath);
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            if (resource.isReadable()) {
                MetadataReader metadataReader = metadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(resource);
                if (isCandidate(metadataReader)) {
                    candidates.add(Class.forName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName()));
                }
            }
        }
        return candidates;
    }
    public String resolveBasePackage(String basePackage) {
        return ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath(SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(basePackage));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public boolean isCandidate(MetadataReader metadataReader) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName());
            if (c.getAnnotation(Controller.class) != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable e){
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I load the class which has got annotation `@Controller`. It is working fine but I want to load only the class not interface also how do I get the methods and the arguments of the class loaded.

EDIT :

This is how I get all the class names and try to get the methods name :

```
List classNames = hexgenClassUtils.findMyTypes("com.hexgen.*");
            Iterator<Class> it = classNames.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                Class obj = it.next(); 
                System.out.println("Class  :"+obj.toString());

                cls = Class.forName(obj.toString());
                Method[] method = cls.getMethods();
                for (Method method2 : method) {
                    System.out.println("Method name : "+method2.toGenericString());
                }
                // TODO  something with obj
            }
```

The problem I face is `class com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI` here class is coming because of which I am not able to load the class dynamically and get the following exception.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI` so how to solve it.

Kindly help me to find the solution.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
        Class c = Class.forName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName());
        if (!c.isInterface() && c.getAnnotation(Controller.class) != null) {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Great :). It helped me. i am not able to accept the answer for some reason. Will do it after three minutes. i face one problem now. will update the question please help me to resolve it

Comment: Use obj.getName() here Class.forName(obj.toString());

Comment: :) solved it. thanks a lot. now i am able to get class and methods name how to get the arguments for the methods. the method may take one or more arguments?

Comment: Sorry, doubled over your answer! Typed it out then took a phone call and posted without seeing you had answered.

Comment: James not an issue. Thanks for the effort.